# unable to create following folder structure in gulp?

Tags: gulp

I have project structure like this

```
-moduleA
   -styles
   -scripts

-moduleB
   -styles
   -scripts

-styles
-scripts
```

i want to get output so ending structure would like

```
-moduleA
   -styles
   -scripts

-moduleB
   -styles
   -scripts

-styles
-scripts

-build
   -moduleA
      -styles
      -scripts
   -moduleB
     -styles
     -scripts
```

Comment: Do you just want to copy the files?

Comment: no i want to minify css & js also

Answer (score 1):

To copy folders and their contents to a new `build` folder simply use:

```
gulp.task('copy', function(){
  return gulp.src(['./moduleA', './moduleB'])
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build')
})
```

You can do whatever processing you need to along the way by but specifying dependencies. ie:

```
gulp.task('transpile', function(){
  return gulp.src(['moduleA', 'moduleB'])
    .pipe(bable())
})

gulp.task('copy', function(){
  return gulp.src(['moduleA', 'moduleB'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build')
})

gulp.task('build', ['minify', 'copy']);
```